# How to access JSON element using regex or array index in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, regex

I am trying to read JSON elements **"unit"** and **"value"** using PHP. However, some JSON elements ("local/sysbench-cpu-1.0.0", "m4.4xlarge-4.4.0-66-generic") may not be the same in each JSON. That is why I want to use regex or the array index to access elements rather then a particular string:

```
{
    "title": "cputests-sysbench-cpu-100-m4-4xlarge-20170328",
    "results": {
        "local\/sysbench-cpu-1.0.0": {
            "arguments": "cpu performance benchmark",
            "units": "seconds",
            "results": {
                "m4.4xlarge-4.4.0-66-generic": {
                    "value": "53.2386"
                }
            }
        },
        "": {
            "arguments": "Memory Usage Monitor",
            "units": "Megabytes",
            "results": {
                "m4.4xlarge-4.4.0-66-generic": {
                    "value": "1355,1356,1357,1357,1358,1359,1358,1359,1359,1358,1357,1358,1369,1370,1374,1373,1374,1376,1370,1362,1359,1360,1358,1358,1357,1358,1360,1360,1359,1359,1362,1362,1362,1363,1362,1363,1366,1365,1369,1366,1365,1363,1362,1363,1362,1363,1363,1363,1368,1374,1373,1372,1372,1373"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The PHP script works if I don't use regex or array index:

```
<?php 
$string = file_get_contents("result.json"); <br>
$data = json_decode($string); <br>
//$data = json_decode($string, true);

//var_dump(json_decode($string)); <br>


print $data->{'results'}->{**'local/sysbench-cpu-1.0.0'**}->units; <br>
print "\n";<br>
print $data->{'results'}->{'local/sysbench-cpu-1.0.0'}->{'results'}->{'**m4.4xlarge-4.4.0-66-generic**'}->value; <br>

// print $data['results']['local/sysbench-cpu-1.0.0']['units']; <br>
// print "\n"; <br>
// print $data['results']['local/sysbench-cpu-1.0.0']['results']['m4.4xlarge-4.4.0-66-generic']['value']; <br>
?>
```

Any attempt to use regex in place of a string or array index when using `json_decode($string, true)` fails.

Comment: Why do you want to use regex? If `json_decode` work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `foreach` loop to go over the `results`...

```
foreach ($json->results as $key => $results) {
  ...
  // access to $results->units

  foreach ($results as $x => $item) {
    ...
    // access to $item->value
  }
}
```

Then it won't matter what they key is. Something along those lines.

Comment: This is of course assuming that this is the data structure you will have.

Comment: Second foreach does not work. Not sure if I am using it correctly.  I am using it as a nested loop.foreach ($data->{'results'} as $key => $results) {
    echo $results->units; 
    foreach ($results as $x => $item){
        echo $item->value;
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

PHP's JSON parsing only returns a plain old associative array, or an object. Neither of these support using regexes as lookups. If you insist on using native PHP, you'll have to `foreach` your way through the keys and values.

Or, you might take a look at something like [JsonPath](https://github.com/FlowCommunications/JSONPath) which allows you to load up JSON, and then use a query string that looks very close to shell globbing:

```
$data = ['people' => [['name' => 'Joe'], ['name' => 'Jane'], ['name' => 'John']]];
$result = (new JSONPath($data))->find('$.people.*.name'); // returns new JSONPath
```

So in your case, your `find()` string would be something like `$.results.*.units` for the unit values, and `$.results.*.results.*.value` for the values. There's probably an even fancier query string that would return both units and values at the same time.